# Angular - Is there list of HostListener-Events?

Tags: angular

I am using a hostlistener in a directive to detect "blur"- and "keyup"-events.
Now I need to detect changes in the input-element the directive sits on. I tried

```
@HostListener('change', ['$event'])
```

but it does not fire.

Is there a "change"-event? I have also read, that there should be an "input"-event, but that does not fire either.

So, my question is:
Is there a list of available events that I can use?

I have searched google:

[https://www.google.de/search?q=angular+2+list+of+hostlistener+events](https://www.google.de/search?q=angular%202%20list%20of%20hostlistener%20events)

and the angular-documentation:

https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener

but did not find anything.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Open angular dom element schema https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler/src/schema/dom_element_schema_registry.ts#L78

where:

- (no prefix): property is a string.
- `*`: property represents an event.
- `!`: property is a boolean.
- `#`: property is a number.
- `%`: property is an object.

Then press `ctrl+F` and write `*`

[image]

`@HostListener`(and also `(customEvent)="handler()"`) can also listen to custom events

**[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzm1cw?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: THANK YOU FOR THIS ANSWER! Your stackblitz link is a goldmine of information as I'm learning HostListener and customer attribute directives now. Seeing a custom event is a huge help in bringing these concepts together for me personally.

Comment: Not a useful answer really, unless you are keen to read all /* comments */. The question was on the list, not tricky workarounds.

Comment: I do not find why `@HostListener('DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument')` is working and what would be the event for a node deleted.

Answer (score 30):

The list of events you can listen to can be found here

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

and I believe this one is the same, but better organized (I'm not sure if all are valid)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.  It has drop and other does not.

Answer (score 14):

Sorry, I think you ask about a list of properties. You can use e.g.

```
@HostListener("focus", ["$event.target"])
  onFocus(target) {
    console.log(target.value)
  }

  @HostListener("blur", ["$event.target"])
  onBlur(target) {
    console.log(target.value)

  }
  @HostListener("input", ["$event.target.value"])
  onInput(value) {
    console.log(value)

  }
```

Comment: This is a large part of the solution. If you're not using the element itself you would do better to set the event this way! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted an answer showing all the ones like this:
`document:keydown.escape`

within the context of this kind of snippet in Angular:

```
import { HostListener}    from '@angular/core';
@HostListener('document:keydown.escape', ['$event']) 
  onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {

  }
```

1. [This website](http://alligator.io/angular/binding-keyup-keydown-events) gave a few examples.
2. [Here](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents-key/#named-key-attribute-values) is a more complete list.
3. [Here](https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/four-ways-of-listening-to-dom-events-in-angular-part-1-event-binding-3ec7e9f51a1d) is a more generic overview of the alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

The `change` event is [applied to selects](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp).

If you tried with the `input` event, and it still doesn't work, then your directive is the issue.

Did you imported / exported it ? Do you have any console errors ? Is another event fired from your directive ?

Comment: just dom events. You have a list e.g. in https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp (remove the "on" and you have all)

Comment: oninput is a DOM event ... I mean, could you try using a click event for sintance, and see if your code triggers ? This would tell us if the issue is with the directive, or the event

Comment: from oninput -->@HostListener('input',[$event])

Comment: Yeah thank you, I'm aware of the events. Would you mind actually answer the question, and tell me if the HostListener used with click works in your directive, or not ?